# External program called with backticks still produces output

Tags: perl, backticks

so I call an external program in perl and want to capture it's output:

```
my @RNAalifoldOut = `RNAalifold some parameters`;
```

If called from command line the output consists of three lines, e.g:

```
4 sequences; length of alignment 48.
__GCCGA_UGUAGCUCAGUUGGG_AGAGCGCCAGACUGAAAAUCAGA 
...((((.....((((.........)))).(((((.......)))))
```

However my array `@RNAalifoldOut` contains only the two last lines and the first line appears directly on the screen when the line is being executed.

How can this be? I thought maybe the program writes the first line to `STDERR`, but isn't that discarded by the backticks operator? And what could I do to hide this output?

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are likely seeing the standard error from *RNAalifold*. Backticks capture only the standard output.

Capture both standard output and standard error by changing your code to

```
my @RNAalifoldOut = `RNAalifold some parameters 2>&1`;
```

To discard the standard error, use

```
my @RNAalifoldOut = `RNAalifold some parameters 2>/dev/null`;
```

on Unix-like platforms. On Windows, use

```
my @RNAalifoldOut = `RNAalifold some parameters 2>nul`;
```